# The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Main>)?

Tags: java, class, exception, printing, error-handling

What I want to do is print a custom error message that prints the class and function that the error resulted in. To get the class I use `getClass()`. However when I try to run my project I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method printException(Exception) in the type ExceptionPrinter is not applicable for the arguments (FileNotFoundException, Class<Main>, String, String)
    The method printException(Exception) in the type ExceptionPrinter is not applicable for the arguments (ParseException, Class<Main>, String, String)

    at Main.main(Main.java)
```

And I don't know why I can't pass in `Class` into the function using `.class`. B/c before I had:

```
ExceptionHandler.printException(e, getClass() + " main() could not find input file");
```

where *ExceptionPrinter.java* `printException()` looked like this:

```
public static void printException(Exception e, String message){
    System.err.println(message);
    printException(e);
}
```

And that worked fine.

If anyone could help me so that I can pass in the class name to my *ExceptionPrinter.java* that would be great!

## Code

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            ...

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            ExceptionPrinter.printException(e, Main.class, "main", "Input file not found");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            ExceptionPrinter.printException(e, Main.class, "main", "Exception occurred during parsing");
        }
    }

}
```

**ExceptionPrinter.java**

```
public class ExceptionPrinter {

    public static void printException(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    public static void printException(Exception e, Class class, String function, String message){
        System.err.println(class + " " + function + "(): " + message);
        printException(e);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You may stop ignoring the compiler issue in your `ExceptionPrinter` class. `class` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: @Tom yes i realized that was the reason, thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int a=2/0;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            ExceptionPrinter.printException(e, Main.class, "main", "Input file not found");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ExceptionPrinter.printException(e, Main.class, "main", "Exception occurred during parsing");
        }
    }

}
```

**ExceptionPrinter.java**

> In java class is a keyword, So you can't declare like a variable,
>   i.e Change **Class class** to **Class c** or any

```
public class ExceptionPrinter {

    public static void printException(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static void printException(Exception e, Class c, String function, String message){
        //System.err.println(class + " " + function + "(): " + message);
        printException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your ExceptionPrinter is not the latest compiled version you are using and probably it's class only has  `public static void printException(Exception e)` method and not the other one. Compile this first. If you would have used build tools that compiles all dependent code, by default then you would not have seen this.

Exception `The method printException(Exception) in the type ExceptionPrinter is not applicable for the arguments (FileNotFoundException, Class<Main>, String, String)` suggest other overloaded method is not found

Answer (score 0):

Change your overloaded method signature to:

```
public static void printException(
    final Exception execption, 
    final Class clazz, 
    final String function, 
    final String message)
```

- `class` is a reserved word in Java and can't be used as a parameter name.
- Added `final` because it's a good practice to use.